# Path from root to a given node n-ary tree lisp without map/lambda/labels

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp

I know this has been asked before but it has been solved only with map/lambda/labels and I want it solved as basic as possible

I want to return the path from the root to a given node of a tree that looks like this:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
   / \
  D   E
```

given as: (A 2 B 0 C 2 D 0 E 0)
Path from A (root) to given node E is: A C E

I have no idea how to keep the path before finding where exactly the element is.
Should I save the partial result? Any help please?

I tried checking if the element is in but... I just can't construct the path

```
(defun isinh (l a p)
  (cond ((null l) p)
        ((equal (car l) a) (isinh (cdr l) a 1))
        (t (isinh (cdr l) a p))))

(defun isin (l a)
  (cond (t (isinh l a 0))))

(defun p15 (l el)
  (cond ((null l) '())
        ((equal (car l) el) (list el))
        ((and (listp (car l))
              (= (isin (car l) el)))
         (p15 (car l) el))
        ((and (listp (cadr l))
              (= (isin (cadr l) el)))
         (p15 (cadr l) el))
        ((not (equal (car l) el))
         (cons (car l) (p15 (cdr l) el)))))
```

Comment: I added what I tried but it's not working. I can't figure out how to save the path

Comment: just return the path.

Comment: You may want to format your code, write a short documentation line for each function and write tests. As it looks now, from a basic software engineering point of view, this is a mess.

Comment: I totally agree and I am sorry for that, I posted half from the phone, half from a pc. I was in a hurry somewhat. Won't happen again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to transform the tree in a list structure, where the first element is the root, the second element is the left child, and third element is the right child, and then search a path with a simple recursive function.

To transform the tree in a list structure, see the answers to this question: [transforming trees in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182123/transforming-trees-in-lisp).

A recursive function that finds the path is the following:

```
(defun path(tree el)
  (cond ((null tree) nil)
        ((eql (first tree) el) (list el))
        (t (let ((lpath (path (second tree) el)))
             (if lpath
               (cons (first tree) lpath)
               (let ((rpath (path (third tree) el)))
                 (when rpath
                   (cons (first tree) rpath))))))))
```

**UPDATE**

The previous version works only for binary trees, a versione for n-ary trees is the following:

```
(defun path(tree el)
  (cond ((null tree) nil)
        ((eql (car tree) el) (list el))
        (t (loop for child in (rest tree)
              for child-path = (path child el)
              when child-path
              do (return-from path (cons (car tree) child-path))))))

(path '(a (b (c)) (d (e) (f)) (g (h) (i (j)))) 'j)  ;  =>  (A G I J)
```

Comment: Uhm after checking it again...  this function is not really working for n-ary trees is it? It only works for binary so far

Comment: Yes, your example was on a binary tree, so I supposed that the request was about binary trees. But it is not difficult to extend `path` to n-ary trees.

Comment: It wasmentioned in the title it's about n-ary. How would I transform it to work on n-ary since it's made all on left and right?

Comment: Udated the answer. Note that to transform a tree from the array-like notation to list notation the algorithm described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34195005/2382734) can be used.

Comment: I will accept it even though it is not really what I'm looking for. I want something using only recursion, no loops/for/when/do but I forgot to specify it in the post so it's alright. I will see what can be done there in the T path, to change everything to recursion. Thank you!